# Joint probability mass function $f$ of $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $\Omega$={$20, 21, ..., 49$},   $P(i)=\begin{cases}0.05,  & \text{if $20<=i<=29$} \\0.03, & \text{if $30<=i<=39$}  \\0.02, & \text{if $40<=i<=49$}\end{cases}$

The random variables $X, Y$ are defined as:

$X(i)=\begin{cases}5,  & \text{if $20<=i<=24$} \\10, & \text{if $25<=i<=34$}  \\15, & \text{if $35<=i<=49$}\end{cases}$

$Y(i)=\begin{cases}10,  & \text{if $20<=i<=23$} \\5, & \text{if $24<=i<=28$}  \\15, & \text{if $29<=i<=39$} \\10, & \text{if $40<=i<=49$}\end{cases}$

Calculate the joint probability mass function $f$ of $(X,Y)$ for: $f(5,5)$, $f(5,10)$ and $f(5,15)$.

Ok here my attempt:

$f(5,5)=P(X=5, Y=5)$=P({24})=0.05

$f(5,10)=P(X=5, Y=10)$=P({20, 21, 22 , 23})=4*0.05=0.2

$f(5,15)=P(X=5, Y=15)=0$

Answer (score 1):

It is alright although you could give more details.

Do you have another question?

Comment: We have had little to no information about probability mass functions. Is the PMF to discrete distributions what the CDF is for continuous distributions?

Comment: No. The exact analogue to the pmf in the continuous case is the pdf (probability density function). The good thing is that hte pmf of discrete a random variable always exists.